# So confused on what version I made my application for and what version my phone runs

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework

HP iPAQ 110 Classic Handheld. I made an application that uses windows mobile 6.0 professional SDK with .net 3.5 framework.

the phone settings sates

```
windows mobile 6 classic
CE OS 5.2.1616(Build 181200.0.4.0).
```

So why is it when I try to run my application it I get

> MissingMethodException
>
> This application requires a newer
>   version of the MS .NET compact
>   framework than the version installed
>   on this device.

I also went to there site and got the newest drivers they had(well I think it is the newest).

My version now is 1.01.06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need new *drivers* but it sounds like you need to install version 3.5 of the Compact Framework, which you can [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en).

Comment: Hmm I downloaded that I connected my device to my computer as it says to do. I then doubled clicked the .msi and when it started to install it asked me if I wanted to remove or repair the it since it is installed on my computer already. So it wanted to like reinstall over the one in my computer not anything with the phone

Comment: Try again. If that is the error message you are receiving then this is almost definately the solution. Do you get this problem when running from Visual Studio? I ask this because VS installs the required framework before running your application.